# What do the characteristics of optimisation problems mean?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

In evolutionary algorithms, do the characteristics of optimisation problems include local optima and global optima and their distribution? or is the premature convergence considered as one characteristic of optimisation problems?

Comment: depends on where you are using it

Answer (score 2):

An optimization problem asks for an assignment of values to some variables that produces a maximum or minimum result from some function (called the objective function) of those variables.

Often there are many variables and non-smooth/complex objective functions with many local maxima or minima, which is what makes optimization problems difficult.

Evolutionary algorithms and similar techniques are designed to solve optimization problems when the objective function has many inputs and lacks any *specific* special form.